# How can I open port 80?

Tags: 11.04, dyndns

I wanted to open port 80, because I wanted to host from my localmachine using dyndns.org; I followed the steps where it said me to install ddclient for dynamic IP.

Now I need to know how to open this port 80 from Ubuntu.

Can I use iptables for port forwarding.

Comment: add your current iptables rules if you can. Usually ubuntu doesnt block all incoming communication. Do you have installed web server ? ( apache2, lighttpd, nginx or others... ). Little more info about your network would be nice too... are you behind your router, or do you have public IP from your ISP or ? describe your situation please.

Comment: I'm going to guess he's behind a router, and that being the case you'll need to do a port trigger or port forward. If you can get online (as in the internet) then port 80 is "open". Port 80 and port 8080 is http traffic which if your web browser works and gets online is working.

Comment: I'm behind a ISP currently running simple http aps using nodejs or sometimes using nginx; using linsys router WRT54G; I think my ISP generate dynamic IP;

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: Many service providers don't want you to use port 80 and will explicitely block this unless you buy a higher level of service (e.g. business service). I've gotten around this by using a different port. You should verify that your service provider allows port 80 to be used incoming.

Comment: This isn't really an ubuntu question. Please see here. http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for You don't use iptables for port forwarding unless you have iptables on the external box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, but i think that what you need is to host a website from your Ubuntu box which will be available through a dyndns.org FQDN.

So, there are two different things that you need to do.

1. **Set up your dyndns**. Again, this can be done in 2 different ways:

1.1. Configure a cron job for `ddclient`.

The script will connect to dyndns.org website and update your IP address at regular intervals.
This solution is usually needed when ADSL routers don't provide native support for DDNS.

1.2. Configure your router to directly connect to dyndns.org and update the IP address everytime
it changes.

Your model (WRT54G) **supports** DDNS so it's quite easy. You can find more info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111080300/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/saifkhan/archive/2008/12/28/setup-dyndns-dynamic-dns-on-a-linksys-wrt54g-router.aspx)

2. **Forward all incoming requests (i.e. from the Internet) to your Ubuntu webserver.**

That is, configure once again your router to accept all incoming requests from the Internet for port 80 and forward them to port 80 of your Ubuntu machine.

Again, more information about port-forwarding can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322184649/http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/)

Comment: Its working now ... thanks 
Site - http://nodebuzz.dyndns.info/